# mongoengine connection pymongo.GEOSPHERE

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

Running into the following error after installing

```
pip install mongoctl
```

Error Trace

```
packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 415, in <module>
    class GeoJsonBaseField(BaseField):
  File "/Users/anujacharya/.virtualenvs/party/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 420, in GeoJsonBaseField
    _geo_index = pymongo.GEOSPHERE
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GEOSPHERE'
```

Resolution:

Make sure to update the pymongo on your virtualenv

```
pymongo==2.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the latest pymongo